# Why sqlite is allowing second process to do write operation while first process is already doing write

Tags: c, linux, database, sqlite, locking

I have written two process code both codes are copied below , let us assume sqlitep1.c refers to p1 and sqlitep2.c refers to p2

p1 constantly reads from database file sample.db and p2 writes to database file sample.db,

I executed one instances of p2 & p3 and one instances of p1, as per sqlite documentation, two process cannot simultaneously write to sqlite.

in code sqlitep2.c i have two version, one which opens connection and do write and then close (p2) and another version which opens connection and  writes to db file and blocks with while(1), As shown in second version of sqlitep2.c which is executed as p3.

I first executed p3 and then p2, As per code p3 will block after writing, at this point I assume sqlite lock is not released as the connection is not closed.

But in my result I can see p2 is able to write without getting any busy error even though p3 has not released the lock.

Note : Executed in linux machine.

sqlitep1.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include </sqlite/sqlite3.h>

int main()
{
    sqlite3_stmt *pSqlStmt = NULL;
    sqlite3 *pSqlHandle = NULL;
    int ret = SQLITE_ERROR;
    char *pcSharedPath = "sample.db";
    char* pcSqlQuery = NULL;
    char *name = NULL;
    int retry_count = 0;

    while (1)
    {
        printf ("process 1.....\n");
        printf ("-----------------------------\n\n");
            ret = SQLITE_ERROR;
        /*open connection to sqlite*/
        while (ret != SQLITE_OK) {
            printf ("process 1, open connection\n");
            ret = sqlite3_open_v2 (pcSharedPath, &(pSqlHandle), (SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_FULLMUTEX), NULL);
            if (ret != SQLITE_OK)
            {
                printf ("process 1, opening failed....\n");
                if (ret == SQLITE_BUSY)
                {
                    printf ("process 1, open connection busy error....\n");
                }
            }
            sleep(1);
        }
        printf ("process 1, database connection opened...\n");
               /* prepare query */
        ret = SQLITE_ERROR;
        pcSqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM EMP";
        while (ret != SQLITE_OK)
        {
            ret = sqlite3_prepare_v2 (pSqlHandle, pcSqlQuery, -1,  &pSqlStmt, NULL);
            if (ret == SQLITE_BUSY) {
                printf ("process 1, prepare busy error....\n");
            }
            if (ret == SQLITE_ERROR) {
                printf("SQLITE_ERROR\n");
            }
            sleep(1);
        }
        printf ("process 1, prepare success...\n");
        /* extract result from query */
        while(1)
        {
            ret = sqlite3_step (pSqlStmt);
            if (ret == SQLITE_DONE)
                break;
            if (ret != SQLITE_ROW) {
                printf("process 1, no row exists...\n");
                break;
            }
            name = sqlite3_column_text (pSqlStmt, 1);
            printf ("%s \n", name);
        }

        /* finalize */
        if (NULL != pSqlStmt)
        {
    ret = SQLITE_ERROR;
            // while (ret != SQLITE_OK) {
                ret = sqlite3_finalize (pSqlStmt);
                printf ("process 1, Finalizing %d...\n", ret);
            // }
            pSqlStmt = NULL;
        }
        /* close sqlite connection */
        ret = SQLITE_ERROR;
            retry_count = 0;
            while (ret != SQLITE_OK && retry_count != 5) {
          ret = sqlite3_close(pSqlHandle);
                printf("sqlite3_close %d...\n", ret);
                retry_count++;
            }
            retry_count=0;
        if (SQLITE_OK != ret) {
            printf ("sqlite close failed....Exiting process 1...\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

first version of sqlitep2.c which does not block after write operation( no while(1))

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include </sqlite/sqlite3.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    sqlite3_stmt *pSqlStmt = NULL;
    sqlite3 *pSqlHandle = NULL;
    int ret = SQLITE_ERROR;
    char *pcSharedPath = "sample.db";
    char pcSqlQuery[100] = "";
    char *name = NULL;
    int i = atoi(argv[1]);
    int retry_count = 0;

    while (1)
    {
        printf ("process 2.....\n");
        printf ("-----------------------------\n\n");
        ret = SQLITE_ERROR;
        /*open connection to sqlite*/
        while (ret != SQLITE_OK) {
            printf ("process 2, open connection\n");
            ret = sqlite3_open_v2 (pcSharedPath, &(pSqlHandle), (SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_FULLMUTEX), NULL);
            if (ret != SQLITE_OK)
            {
                printf ("process 2, opening failed %d....\n", ret);
                if (ret == SQLITE_BUSY)
                {
                    printf ("process 2, open connection busy error....\n");
                }
            }
            usleep(10*1000);
        }
        printf ("process 2, database connection opened...\n");
        sqlite3_busy_timeout(pSqlHandle, 1000);

    /* prepare query */
    ret = SQLITE_ERROR;
        char name[50];
    while (ret != SQLITE_OK && retry_count != 10)
    {
                pSqlStmt = NULL;
                sqlite3_snprintf(50, name, "\"Sachin%d\"", i);
                sqlite3_snprintf(100,pcSqlQuery, "INSERT INTO EMP VALUES (%d, %s)", i, name);
                printf ("%s\n", pcSqlQuery);
          ret = sqlite3_prepare_v2 (pSqlHandle, "INSERT INTO EMP(ID, NAME) VALUES (?1, ?2);", -1,  &pSqlStmt, NULL);
                sqlite3_bind_int(pSqlStmt, 1, i);
                sqlite3_bind_text(pSqlStmt, 2, name, -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
          if (ret == SQLITE_BUSY) {
              printf ("process 2, prepare busy error....\n");
          }
          else {
                if (ret == SQLITE_ERROR)
                {
               printf ("SQLITE_ERROR...\n");
                }
            ret = SQLITE_ERROR;
            while (ret != SQLITE_OK) {
                    ret = sqlite3_step(pSqlStmt);
                printf ("process 2, return from sqlite3_step : %d...\n", ret);
                    if (ret != SQLITE_DONE) {
                            printf ("process 2, insert error...\n");
                    } else if (ret == SQLITE_BUSY) {
                    printf("sqlite3_step busy error...\n");
                } else {
                               i++;
                        ret = SQLITE_OK;
                    }
            }
          }
                printf ("process 2, ret value of insert op %d\n ", ret);
            usleep(10*1000);
                retry_count++;
      }
      retry_count=0;
      printf ("process 2, prepare success...\n");
      /* finalize */
      if (NULL != pSqlStmt)
      {
            ret = SQLITE_ERROR;
            while (ret != SQLITE_OK) {
                ret = sqlite3_finalize (pSqlStmt);
                printf ("process 2, Finalizing %d...\n", ret);
            }
          pSqlStmt = NULL;
      }
      /* close sqlite connection */
            ret = SQLITE_ERROR;
            retry_count = 0;
        ret = sqlite3_close(pSqlHandle);
            while (ret != SQLITE_OK) {
          ret = sqlite3_close(pSqlHandle);
                printf("sqlite3_close %d...\n", ret);
                retry_count++;
            sleep(1);
            }
            retry_count=0;
            pSqlHandle = NULL;
   if (SQLITE_OK != ret) {
            printf ("sqlite close failed....Exiting process 2...\n");
            return 0;
        }
            sleep(1);
    }
}
```

Second version of sqlitep2.c which has a infinite block while(1) after write operation, which means it is not releasing the lock.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include </sqlite/sqlite3.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    sqlite3_stmt *pSqlStmt = NULL;
    sqlite3 *pSqlHandle = NULL;
    int ret = SQLITE_ERROR;
    char *pcSharedPath = "sample.db";
    char pcSqlQuery[100] = "";
    char *name = NULL;
    int i = atoi(argv[1]);
    int retry_count = 0;

    while (1)
    {
        printf ("process 2.....\n");
        printf ("-----------------------------\n\n");
        ret = SQLITE_ERROR;
        /*open connection to sqlite*/
        while (ret != SQLITE_OK) {
            printf ("process 2, open connection\n");
            ret = sqlite3_open_v2 (pcSharedPath, &(pSqlHandle), (SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_FULLMUTEX), NULL);
            if (ret != SQLITE_OK)
            {
                printf ("process 2, opening failed %d....\n", ret);
                if (ret == SQLITE_BUSY)
                {
                    printf ("process 2, open connection busy error....\n");
                }
            }
            usleep(10*1000);
        }
        printf ("process 2, database connection opened...\n");
        sqlite3_busy_timeout(pSqlHandle, 1000);

    /* prepare query */
    ret = SQLITE_ERROR;
        char name[50];
    while (ret != SQLITE_OK && retry_count != 10)
    {
                pSqlStmt = NULL;
                sqlite3_snprintf(50, name, "\"Sachin%d\"", i);
                sqlite3_snprintf(100,pcSqlQuery, "INSERT INTO EMP VALUES (%d, %s)", i, name);
                printf ("%s\n", pcSqlQuery);
          ret = sqlite3_prepare_v2 (pSqlHandle, "INSERT INTO EMP(ID, NAME) VALUES (?1, ?2);", -1,  &pSqlStmt, NULL);
                sqlite3_bind_int(pSqlStmt, 1, i);
                sqlite3_bind_text(pSqlStmt, 2, name, -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
          if (ret == SQLITE_BUSY) {
              printf ("process 2, prepare busy error....\n");
          }
          else {
                if (ret == SQLITE_ERROR)
                {
               printf ("SQLITE_ERROR...\n");
                }
            ret = SQLITE_ERROR;
            while (ret != SQLITE_OK) {
                    ret = sqlite3_step(pSqlStmt);
                printf ("process 2, return from sqlite3_step : %d...\n", ret);
                    if (ret != SQLITE_DONE) {
                            printf ("process 2, insert error...\n");
                    } else if (ret == SQLITE_BUSY) {
                    printf("sqlite3_step busy error...\n");
                } else {
                               i++;
                        ret = SQLITE_OK;
                    }
            }
          }
                printf ("process 2, ret value of insert op %d\n ", ret);
            usleep(10*1000);
                retry_count++;
      }
      while (1) {} // block here, DO NOT proceed further.
      retry_count=0;
      printf ("process 2, prepare success...\n");
      /* finalize */
      if (NULL != pSqlStmt)
      {
            ret = SQLITE_ERROR;
            while (ret != SQLITE_OK) {
                ret = sqlite3_finalize (pSqlStmt);
                printf ("process 2, Finalizing %d...\n", ret);
            }
          pSqlStmt = NULL;
      }
      /* close sqlite connection */
            ret = SQLITE_ERROR;
            retry_count = 0;
        ret = sqlite3_close(pSqlHandle);
            while (ret != SQLITE_OK) {
          ret = sqlite3_close(pSqlHandle);
                printf("sqlite3_close %d...\n", ret);
                retry_count++;
            sleep(1);
            }
            retry_count=0;
            pSqlHandle = NULL;
   if (SQLITE_OK != ret) {
            printf ("sqlite close failed....Exiting process 2...\n");
            return 0;
        }
            sleep(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this have anything to do with soft-locks? Or that sqlite simply blocks calls during operations and releases them as soon as there's no event being executed? *(I'm curious, I have no answer for this)*

Comment: @Torxed, As per sqlite documentation, Two threads/processes cannot simultaneously write to same sqlite file, Im not sure about when exactly sqlite will lock the file and unlock the file. Im wondering how p2 is able to write continuously while p3 has not done sqlite3_close(), I believe sqlite3_close is the one which release the lock..OR Im not sure when lock is released.

Comment: Why do you think SQLite's internal mutex is not released between calls of sqlite APIs? in other words, why do you think mutex is still locked when p2 exited funcation call `sqlite3_step` ?

Comment: @nivpeled, What Im guessing is, p3 holds the lock infinitely on sample.db, because it has opened connection and then started writing and there is  while(1) in p3, However when p2 opens connection and try writing, I suppose p2 should get busy error because p3 has not release the lock.

Comment: @BeingKS I think it's the calls themselves creating the lock/unlock just before and after execution. Since the point of databases is that multiple end-points should be able to use the resource. Just not at the same time of certain executions. So `open()` doesn't create a lock, maybe a soft-lock but not a complete I/O lock. So what nivpeled is fishing after is probably true :)

Comment: I share the same understanding as @Torxed

Comment: You're not using transactions, so the insert acquires a write lock, does its thing, and releases the lock... Do you think it's kept after `sqlite3_step()` returns?

Comment: @Shawn, Could you please elaborate more, I did not understand your question

Comment: @Torxed, I agree to your comment to some extent, But one doubt I have here is, Say one process does sqlite prepare and comes out of API and it means no lock now, What if at this point another process also does prepare? Because after prepare there are bind calls to add the arguments to insert query, which bind will get executed, Wont this result in race condition ?

Comment: Granted that this behavior isn't [guaranteed](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html) (and thus might change in a different release), in this case, sqlite isn't keeping the write lock after the insert finishes even though the statement hasn't been reset or finalized.

Comment: @BeingKS To be honest, I don't and have rarely ever used sqlite. Postgresql / mongodb or any other kind is my poison. I just know programmer logic, and I would say that `bind` only maps values into a prepared statement. That doesn't mean it's being executed at all. In postgresql and Python for instance. I do prepared statements all the time. [prepared statements](http://initd.org/psycopg/articles/2012/10/01/prepared-statements-psycopg/). And usually, unless you do `commit()` on the transaction, it's not a locking action to `INSERT` either, because it's a ghost copy until `commit()`.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite does locks around transactions, not open connections.  Without an explicit transaction (which you don't appear to be doing) each SQL statement is a separate transaction that ends when the statement is executed.  Your having an unfinalized statement means nothing, as "step" executed your INSERT and released the lock.